# Fetch JSON is causing infinity loop using react state

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

the JSON is something list this:

```html
{
  "orders": [
    {
      id: 123456789,
      description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    },
    {
      id: 789456123,
      description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    }    
  ]
}
```

*sorry for hiding the url*

The code:

```html
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Search from "./components/Search";


function App() {
  
  const [currentURL, setCurrentURL] = useState([]);

  
  let ordersUrl = "MYURL";
  useEffect( () => {
    fetch(ordersUrl, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} }).then((response) => response.json() ).then( data => setCurrentURL(data.orders));
    //fetch(url).then((response) => response.json() ).then( data => setCurrentURL(data));
  })
  
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

  function changeFilter(event){    
    // console.log(event.target.value);
    setFilter( event.target.value );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Search onChange={changeFilter}  />
      {filter}
      
      {
        currentURL.map(x => x && <div>{x.description}</div>)
        //currentURL.filter( f => { return f.name.includes(filter);}).map(x => x && <div key={x.id}> {x.name} </div>)
      }
      
      {/* filter */}
      {/* orders */}

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Well, I can list the description no problem ... but when I try to list the ID is causing a infinity loop refreshing the results "something like that".

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is updating your state on success (`setCurrentUrl(data.orders)`), which triggers React to re-render the component, which causes your `useEffect()` to fire again.

Try adding an empty dependencies array to your `useEffect()`, so that it only runs the first time (and not on every update):

```
useEffect(
  () => { ... stuff ...},
  []
);
```

You can also have a read through [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to get a better understanding of what is happening here.